# CAN/CAN FD Channels ValueCAN4-2

Tags: can

I'm very confused right now. The device has two channels which each can be CAN or [CAN FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_FD).

Can I send a CAN message to its CAN-FD channel?

Comment: What’s CAN FD? ...

Comment: [CAN FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_FD) - *"CAN with Flexible Data-Rate ... an extension to the original CAN bus protocol"*

Comment: What is this ValueCAN4-2 device? Do you have a reference to it and/or some more information (e.g. how it is configured (DIP switches, sending messages to it via CAN or a non-CAN interface), CANopen / J1939 / other, etc.)? (Respond by editing your question, not here in comments.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not yet able to edit my own post. But ValueCAN4-2 is a tool for CAN FD and is backward compatible with CAN 2.0. It has 2 channels w/c supports CAN/CANFD. More details can be found here: https://www.intrepidcs.com/products/vehicle-network-adapters/valuecan-4/valuecan-4-2-overview I'm just a bit confused, because it says that each channel supports either CAN or CANFD, does that mean I can send a CAN message over CANFD channel?

Comment: "The device" _What_ "device"? This is far too broad to be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I send a CAN message to its CAN-FD channel?

You can either use the device in CAN mode, or in CAN FD mode.

CAN FD and normal CAN are not compatible on the same bus. Since a FD frame would look like an error for normal CAN controllers.

Comment: Thank you, atleast some things were made cleared. It's very hard since I dont have yet the device itself.